# Remove embedded source filenames from shared libraries

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

When I build a shared library "mylib.so" from a source file "secret.cc", the resulting shared object contains the source filename:

...  **do_global_ctors_aux^@secret.cc^@__DTOR_END**  ...

But I don't want to divulge the name of that file ("secret.cc") to the users of my library. Is there a way to strip the filename information from the shared object, or to prevent it from being inserted in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

It's quite simple: Don't let the compiler know the source's filename from the very beginning. Instead of

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -Wall -c my_source.cc -o my_source.o
```

do this:

```
cat my_source.cc | g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -Wall -c -x c++ - -o my_source.o
```

Note that you need to provide `-x c++` explicitly, the error messages obviously won't contain the filename anymore and there is one additional caveat: When your sources contain relative includes, i.e., includes in quotes (`#include "foo.hpp"`) instead of angle brackets (`#include <foo.hpp>`), those will no longer work as the compiler can't refer to the file's directory, it just sees a byte-stream from a pipe.