# How to strip from object code generated by g++ the strings representing absolute paths to source headers

Tags: c++, gcc

By running `strings` I have noticed that the object code generated by my `g++ 4.7.3`compiler  (without turning on the debug flag) contains the absolute paths to all the headers used in the source code units. Doing a `strip -s` on the object code does not remove those strings. Why are they included in an object code in the first place? Secondly, how can I remove them from the object code?

Comment: Could it be that you have asserts in your program? The `assert` macro frequently expands into something that contains `__FILE__`.

Comment: I'll check but don't think I have any asserts or  `__FILE__` enabled for production

Comment: Try to compile with [`-DNDEBUG`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/assert.h.html).

Comment: @zneak `assert` shouldn't normally output the full path.

Comment: @JamesKanze, [`assert` refers to `__FILE__`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/assert.html), which [does include the full path](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html).

Comment: The compiler as such does not add strings containing filenames to the compiled code. It comes from SOMETHING such as `__FILE__` that adds it to the source for a reason. You need to find that and remove those bits. (`__FILE__` will sometimes have the full path and sometimes not, appears to be dependant on the compiler - from memory, visual studio typically does not, where GCC does - and I thin ARMCC does too)

Comment: @zneak -DNDEBUG removed most of the paths. I don't have any `__FILE__` in my sources. But there still are some strings pointing to boost headers, which are included in my headers, for example `/path/to/boost/include/boost/property_tree/string_path.hpp`. I suppose they do use `__FILE__` or assert. I'd like to tell boost to turn off those flags, if there's a boost-standard way.

Comment: @Martin, [boost has its own assert macro that also use `__FILE__`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/boost/assert.hpp). They can be disabled by defining `BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS` (`-DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS` on the g++ command line).

Comment: @zneak `-DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS` does not change the situation. I'll analyze the `boost::property_tree/string_path.hpp` and the remaining two headers from `boost::property_tree` to see why this only boos lib does not follow the `NDEBUG / BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS` rule

Comment: @zneak The standard says that `__FILE__` resolves to "the presumed name of the file".  Nothing about a complete path there, and from a QoI point of view, one certainly wouldn't expect a complete path, _unless_ that was what was given (in combining the `-I` option and the name in the `include`).

Comment: @JamesKanze, yes, you are right. Contrary to what I said, `__FILE__` will not necessarily be a full path with gcc.

Comment: @zneak Nor with VC++, or any other compiler I've used.  The full path _will_ appear if you use something like `-I/home/kanze/includes` (I think).  It's actually a good question: what should you expect: no path, the path relative to where you invoked the compiler, or the path relative to the source file?  I suspect that the last is the most useful, but I suspect that most compilers will give you one of the first two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file names and paths are usually from the command line, so if you compile the file with an absolute path, it will show up in the binary. You need to modify how you compile your source files, probably changing the build system. Change:

```
g++ -I/home/frey/mylib/include /home/frey/foo.cpp -o foo
```

to

```
cd /home/frey
g++ -Imylib/include foo.cpp -o foo
```

Comment: That could be true for debug symbols, but if `strip` didn't remove them, then it's somewhere in the data section of the program, and compilers don't embed file names there just for fun. It's a very long shot to say that the file names stay in the executable after a `strip` run because OP uses absolute paths to compile.

Comment: @zneak It's not a long shot as I'm maintaining our project's build system in the company for several years. Symbol/string including the paths show up for several reasons, e.g. `-rdynamic` and those are not removed by `strip`. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15688992/2073257) about removing the source file names altogether.

Comment: @zneak That _should_ also impact `__FILE__` (at least in a good implementation).

Comment: @JamesKanze, do you mean that a good implementation of `strip` should be aware of what string is the product of `__FILE__` so that it can remove it?

Comment: @zneak No.  An implementation of `strip` cannot remove any strings that are referenced, and typically, if you've used `__FILE__`, it will be referenced.  I was talking about including the path in `__FILE__` (and I can't seem to make the connection with what you wrote above---I may have been thinking of something else).